# AppsScript setNamedRange results in Service Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just tested this script 10 minutes ago, it worked, and now sudently it's throwing a "Service error: Spreadsheets".

The debugger doesn't show anything, I had to toggle comment gradualy until I found the row that triggers the error:

```
ss.setNamedRange(namesFlat[j], sheet.getRange(j+2, 26));
```

The script pasted below. Any ideas..?

Thanks!
G

```
function onOpen()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuItems = [{name: "Add Validation", functionName: "createNamedRangesAndVaidation"}]
  ss.addMenu("Script", menuItems);
}

function createNamedRangesAndVaidation() 
{
  var ss, sheet, names, links, dataV, namesFlat, rule;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  names = sheet.getRange("y:y").getValues();
  dataV = sheet.getRange("a2");
  namesFlat = []

  for (var i = 1, length = names.length; i < length; i++)
  {
    if (!names[i][0]) break;
    namesFlat.push(names[i][0]);
  }

  for (var j = 0, jlength = namesFlat.length; j < jlength; j++)
  {
    ss.setNamedRange(namesFlat[j], sheet.getRange(j+2, 26));
  }
  rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(namesFlat).build();
  dataV.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is the issue, and it's not with the script directly but with the fact that I have values in the namesFlat[] start with a '=' sign [=value1,=value2,etc.] to create a data validation list that will show the named range when a corresponding value us selected.

I ended up adding this after the named ranges are created:

```
eq = "=";
namesFlat[j] = eq.concat(namesFlat[j]);
```

and that solved it.

Is this the expected behavior? Is it really impossible to work with the = character in strings in scrips?

Thanks